# How to listen click even only for back button in Android?

Tags: android

I am developing for BLE in Android. I use the following code to listen click even of back button.

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.preview_player, container, false) ;
        view.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        view.requestFocus();
        view.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.i(TAG, "keyCode = " + keyCode);
                if(event.getAction() != KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

                }
                return true;

            }
        });
```

The code work when I click the back button and volume button.

How to listen only for back button ?? **(I don't want to listen for volume button.)**

I have try to use `keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK` , but the volume button can not change the volume too...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put return false when it is not back click.

```
      @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i(TAG, "keyCode = " + keyCode);
            if(event.getAction() != KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this method which is best and tested: 
    for API level 5

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // your code.
}
```

and for older then API 5 use this:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        // your code
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Best of Luck

Answer (score 0):

i use these lines of code to listen only to back key:

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
            Intent i = new Intent(kerkoklase2.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Comment: But I use `keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK` , my volume button can not change the volume...

Comment: i just tried on my app that i use this method.
you need to override the onKeyDown method, just copy my code and paste it outside of the method you use(onCreateView), do not try to bind it to the view

Comment: @Wun in your sample code, you do not have the call to super (@virusivv does). Likely what prevents the volume keys from working like normal.